# Generate a pdf file from activity view

Tags: android, android-layout, pdf, view

Is there anyway to generate a pdf file from the actual activity displayed on the screen? I have a scroll view with some text views in it, and I want to get the whole content of the layout (the scroll view) to a pdf file, with the aim to be able to share it afterwards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use itext lib. You have to create pdf similar to your view in different logic

http://sourceforge.net/projects/itext/

Comment: I have it, but is difficult to find a sample.